# How to install Tor on Windows 7 for running a hidden service?

Tags: windows

If I want to run a hidden service on my own Windows, how should I install Tor software on it and then configure the torrc file to add those 2 lines needed for running a hidden service?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Expert Bundle.

You need to create a `torrc` file in C:\Users\you\AppData\Roaming\tor\
It needs to have at least one `HiddenServiceDir` and one `HiddenServicePort` directive.
This is enough to host a hidden service.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to download the Tor Browser. At this point you are going to want to test that the Tor Browser is indeed working. Also you are going to need to have a web server setup. From there you are just going to open the torrc with a notepad editor and change the torrc to fit your existing webserver.

Lines needed in torrc (need to be modified to fit your setup):
HiddenServiceDir C:\Users\username\Documents\tor\hidden_service
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8080

For installing tor browser:
https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-windows.html.en

For configuring torrc / setup webserver:
https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en